# Convert a map to a list of maps with new properties in terraform

Tags: dictionary, tags, terraform

I have a list of tags that I use for different resources:

```
common_tags = {
    Application = "${var.application}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
}
```

I added an aws_autoscaling_group where tags can be also provided, but the structure required is different and has to be defined in this way:

```
tags = [{
    key                 = "explicit1"
    value               = "value1"
    propagate_at_launch = true
}]
```

I need to convert the map of tags to a list of maps with the new structure.

Right now I do this:

```
variable "application" {
  default = "MyApplication"
}

variable "environment" {
  default = "production"
}

locals {
  common_tags = {
    Application = "${var.application}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }

  my_service_tags = "${list(
               map("key", "Name", "value", "my_service_tags-${var.environment}", "propagate_at_launch", true), 
               map("key", "Application", "value", var.application, "propagate_at_launch", true),
               map("key", "Environment", "value", var.environment, "propagate_at_launch", true))}"
}
```

So as you can see the tags are defined twice.

Is there any way of define the new structure (my_service_tags) using the previous one (common_tags) ?

Thanks.